# Made a quiz about myself in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lab for my highschool javascript class and I'm supposed to be using arrays as a way to make a quiz about myself. The lab goes step by step of what I am supposed to do but I still end up not getting my function myQuiz() to not run when I onclick' ed my button

I tried putting the script tags initially in the head but when the function would not run I put it into the end of the body section. But the function still will not run when the button is clicked.

Here's what I have in my script tags:

```
function myQuiz() {
     var questions: ["What is Bryce's favorite color", "What is Bryce's favorite instrument(s) to play?", "When is Bryce's birthday?", "How tall is Bryce?", "Favorite band?"];
     var answers: ["Red", "Double Bass and Violin", "3/24", "6'4", "LOONA"];
     alert("Welcome to WHO IS BRYCE DAVIS?");
     for (var count = 0; count < questions.length; count++) {
         var guess = prompt(questions[count]);
         if (guess == answers[count]) {
            alert('Correct');
         } else {
            alert('WRONG!');
         }
     }
     alert("Thanks for playing!");
}
```

I want there to be a quiz that allows the user to answer and get questions wrong or right.

Comment: Can you add the html? You should be able to set `onclick="myQuiz()"` in your html button.

Comment: One error your code might be returning is in relation to you setting your `var questions `
and `var answers `
using colons (:) use equal signs instead. Like Alec commented, if you could send us a more in-depth report of your code or the errors you are seeing we could give you much more help :)

Answer (score 0):

If using more than one form control (ex. `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc) wrap everything in a `<form>` tag. Doing so allows us to use [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) and [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) APIs -- which gives us easy access to `<form>` and form controls.

It looks like the answers must be typed in by the user -- that requires perfectly matched texts between the anser array and what was typed -- not  good. In the demo, `<input>` and `<output>` tags are dynamically added and when the `<form>` is submitted the value of each `<input>` is matched to an array of answers. The [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method is used so the user's answer is only required to include the text to get a question correct. (ex. "A" and "AB" are both correct because they both include "A"). Details are commented in demo.

```js
const Q = ['What... is your name?', 'What... is your quest?', 'What... is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?'];
const A = ['bryce', 'holy grail', '11'];

// Reference <ol>
const list = document.querySelector('ol');
// Reference <form>
const quiz = document.forms.quiz;

/* 
-for each iteration...
-Add a htmlString (.innerHTML +=) to <ol> (list)...
-Interpolate the question from Q array that corresponds to
 the current index (${Q[i]})
 */
for (let i = 0; i < Q.length; i++) {
  list.innerHTML += `
  <li>${Q[i]}<br>
    <input name='answer' type='text'>
    <output></output> 
  </li>
  `;
}

// Register <form> to submit event -- call QA()
quiz.onsubmit = QA;

/*
-Pass the Event Object
A-Prevent the data of <form> being sent to a server
B-Collect all form controls with the [name='answer'] into
 an array
-for each iteration...
C-Get the value of the <input name='answer'> in the
  position of current index 
D-if the value of the <input> .includes() the string in 
  A array at the corresponding index...
E-Get the <output> that follows the <input> and set it's
  value to 'Correct!'...
F-Otherwise set it's value to "Wrong"
*/
function QA(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //A
  const answers = Array.from(this.elements.answer);//B  
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    let answer = answers[i].value.toLowerCase();//C
    if (answer.includes(A[i])) {//D
      answers[i].nextElementSibling.value = 'Correct!';//E
    } else {
      answers[i].nextElementSibling.value = 'Wrong';//F
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id='quiz'>
  <ol></ol>
  <button type='submit'>Done</button>
</form>
```